# Opening an HTML via WinWord does not preserve the background image

Tags: image, outlook, ms-word, html-email, message-body

The general idea is simple, I want to open an HTML file with ms-Word, An preserve the background image
However, i don't know if i need to aproach from the HTML , CSS, or has something to do with the ms-word file configuration

I have tried the following,alongside some otheres with the usage of `<div>` as a background

Using an background attribute in the body (tested with and without base64 image,usign base64 so there are not missing references)
results in not being shown the background on ms-word, but is shown if open as a webpage

```
<!doctype html>
 <HTML>
 <head></head>
 <body background="data:image/png;base64,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"> 
<p>Some text or something</p> 
<p> that should not be misaligned due to the image being in the background plane</p> 
</body> 
</HTML>
```

Using CSS as an aproach gives the same result, Not being shown on ms-word, but is shown if open as a webpage

```
<!doctype html>
 <HTML>
 <head>
<style>
body{
background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')!important
;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body> 
<p>Some text or something</p> 
<p> that should not be misaligned due to the image being in the background plane</p> 
</body> 
</HTML>
```

Trying to set an image in the background using a negative z-index results in the image being shown as aligned with the text (losing the z-index property) when opening with ms-word, its normal if open as a webpage

```
<!doctype html>
 <HTML>
<head>
</head>
 <body> 
<img height="100" width="100" style="position: absolute;top: 40px; left: 40px;z-index:-1;" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
<p>Some text or something</p> 
<p> that should not be misaligned due to the image being in the background plane</p> 
</body> 
</HTML>
```

in general, seems like adding any `<img>` tag will have the same result, regardless of attributes

About ms-word configurations, I've tried:

1 Enabling  "Options"> "Display" >"Print background colors and images"

2 Enabling  "Options"> "Advanced"> "show background on print view"

3 Saving a doc document with a background image as HTML, and replicating the tags used in (i believe it uses other file to set the images positions)

Comment: AFAIK Word has never really progressed beyond understanding some subset of HTML v.4 (i.e. an HTML standard from over 25 years ago), with some xml "islands" that are only there to "round-trip" Word features when saving and re-opening a Word file. To get anywhere with features from later versions of HTML+CSS you will probably have to transform your HTML in some way or write (say) Word VBA code that looks for the specific elements and attributes you are interested in and transforms them into the nearest Word equivalent.

Comment: Indeed, i had to use VBA tags in order to work
Thanks.

Comment: background images are super technical to get working in Outlook. You would want a html email consultant to help you with that. It involves VML - but then also normal background image code for other email clients

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't support base64 encoded images. Instead, you need to save the image as file to the disk and then add it as an embedded attachment. Only after these steps you can refer to such images in the message body. In VBA you could use the following code for such tasks:

```
attachment = MailItem.Attachments.Add("c:\temp\MyPicture.jpg")
attachment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "MyId1")
MailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>Test image <img src=""cid:MyId1""></body></html>"
```

You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)) article.